# Java Database - Loop through values in a column and insert into database

Tags: java, database

I am trying to create a java program that will lookup a value in a column in a table, and reference a different table to see if the same value is in the table.  If they match, I would like to dump the full data from the first table into a new table.

Basically, I have a table of orders defined by a unique order ID.  I would like to reference that number to a list of returned orders.  If the order was returned, I can then dump the information from the order table to an unsuccessful order table.

I am not sure where to start or if anyone can lead me in the right direction.  I am not super java savvy so any input is helpful.

Comment: And what's your question exactly ? Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Do you want to do this for all values in the table, and then reference those will all values in the other table? Or do you want a specific value in a table, and reference that with the other table?

Comment: @Cruncher I would like to go through all values of the table. I think that it would be more beneficial to look through the returned order table to find the order, then go and use that to find all the data that I would like to output from the order table into the unsuccessful order table

Comment: you can cross join the tables, and take all the rows where this field is matching. If this table exists, then your condition is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by breaking your problem down into smaller steps, until you can code each step.

Procedurally.

- Open a connection to the database.
- Loop through the list of returned orders.
- For each returned order:

  - Read the order from the order table.
  - Write the order to the unsuccessful order table.
- Commit your database changes.
- Close the connection to the database.

Now, do you think you can code something, or do you need to break down further any of these steps?